# How to run multiple curl commands in parallel over https

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to make multiple requests to a server running on localhost in parallel from the command line using `curl`, but I'm having difficulty getting them to run in parallel. One straightforward way to achieve this is something like the following:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++))
do
  time curl -k https://localhost:$PORT/fooBar &
done
```

However, the result of this was the following:

```
"my output"
real    0m7.555s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.002s
"my output"
real    0m14.628s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.002s
"my output"
real    0m21.705s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.002s
"my output"
...
```

This despite the fact that the server is multithreaded and doesn't require locks (I know answerers will be suspicious of this, but consider the next option I tried). Because this appeared send the requests serially, I tried the following:

```
$ time curl -k https://localhost:$PORT/fooBar &
[1] 6780
$ time curl -k https://localhost:$PORT/fooBar &
[2] 6803
$ curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:<my port>

real    0m1.030s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.002s
"my output"
real    0m7.128s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Any ideas why these requests appear to be run serially when executed in a `for` loop with backgrounding and why there's an SSL error when I just use backgrounding directly from the command line?

EDIT: After further research, it appears that the lack of parallelism is because the server is using scala spray, and it appears that requests are being handled by actor in a single thread even though the handler for the endpoints is flagged by `blocking`. This observation splits this question in two. The one relevant to `bash` and `curl` is the fact that the `for` loop and multiple shell one-liners produces different results (one causing an SSL error). Resolving the lack of concurrency on the server side seems like a separate issue.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to reproduce the issue universally, since this is a private server, but I'm hoping someone may have an idea of why the for loop and one-liners might produce different results.

Answer (score 3):

Just launching your processes in background sounds easy and is really tempting, but unless you are iterating on a small set, you would rather not do that.  You can hog the CPU and/or network, since you do not have any control on the amount of concurrent download processes.

I would propose using `xargs`.

```
CONCURRENT_PROCESSES=10
seq 1 9 | 
     xargs -P ${CONCURRENT_PROCESSES}  \
         --replace time curl -k https://localhost:{}/fooBar
```

`xargs`'s `--replace` automatically sets the number of arguments per command invocation to 1 (`-n 1`) and replaces `{}` with each argument given in stdin.

If you want a more complex scenario (such as registering the timing of each individual request), you might want to invoke a wrapping script instead.